# How to not save to SharedPreferences if cancel was clicked on a ListPreference

Tags: java, android

I need to make it so that if cancel or back was pushed when a ListPreference was open that, the value is not saved in SharedPreferences and takes no effect on the app. I have everything in my application working and have been searching for some type of solution but could not find it.
Thanks!
Edit:
Is there a way to start the list preference with none of the values selected?

Comment: I am using a preference fragment by the way

Comment: Use Sushil's answer. When you start the ListPreference, get all the starting values, put it inside a "plain old java object". When the user presses cancel or back, you load the SharedPreference with the Java object you created in onCreate()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I was playing around and figured it out. The way I did it was I made a string in the res/values/string.xml and gave it its own id(@+id/none). Then in the res/xml/preferences.xml in the ListPreference info I added android:defaultValue="id/none". Now when I open the list of preferences nothing is selected as default.

Comment: well nevermind that only worked the first time I ran it....not sure how that is happening

Comment: so I just need to figure out how to clear the Prefrences everytime it starts up I have the whole 'SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("PREF_LIST", MODE_PRIVATE);
  sharedPreferences.edit().clear().commit();'
thats in onCreate but it is not working im about to start pulling my hair out lol

Answer (score 0):

You can handle cancel and back press event explicitly in your app and do the stuff accordingly.

Back button can be handled in following way:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // your code
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: How would I use this to affect what is being/ not being saved to SharedPreferences?

Comment: SharedPrefernces dont save things by default. You must have written that code somewhere. Can you post some code for more clarity?

Comment: Hmm maybe a better way of asking the question is, is there a way to make the List Preference open up with none of the values selected?

Comment: got it!!! the answer on this page saved me!!!
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762248/reset-default-values-of-preference]